# if-else return wrong value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me and correct where I'm wrong. Below is my code when timezone is UK it will print else part why really don't understand.

```
  $user = User::find(BaseHelper::getCurrentUser());
  if($user->timezone ='UK')
  {
      $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->updated, 'GMT');
      $date->timezone("Europe/London");
  } else {
      $date = Carbon::parse($this->updated)->format('d/m/Y h:i A');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this `if($user->timezone ='UK')` to this `if($user->timezone == "UK")`. This will check if `$user->timezone` equals `UK`.

---

If you're tried to set the value of `$user->timezone` to `UK` you need to use `=`, otherwise you need to use `==` or `===`

---

`$a = $b`

- Set `$a` value to `$b`

`$a == $b`

- Equal true: if `$a` is equal to `$b`, after type juggling.

`$a === $b`

- Identical true: if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and they are of the same type.

Comment: I changed this then it is taking else part

Comment: Something weird is happening dont  know why cause when i use '=' then in both condition it is taking if part and when i use '==' then for both condition it is taking else part

Comment: can you dump($user->timezone) and see if the value `timezone` is equal to `UK`

Comment: yes for dump when timezone is available it is showing UK or else blank

Comment: Are you now using `==` or `===`?

Comment: I am using == or = this

Comment: can you `dump($user->timezone == 'UK');`?

Comment: it is giving false for both condition either in table UK is available or not

Comment: Can you contact me at skype? I'll help you futher and post the solution after that

Comment: sure my skype id is puja.kumari134 please add me

Answer (score 7):

You are using `if($user->timezone ='UK')` equal here, when you should use `==`

`=` is for assignment and `==` is for comparing value.

```
if($user->timezone ='UK')
```

will not return true because the value is stored successfully in a variable.